# Using rails-composer, getting error based on builder version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsapps

I'm trying to use [rails-composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer) to start a project. Right after composer installs the gems I get an error and the script stops. Here is the error:

```
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
    composer  Running 'after bundler' callbacks.
The template [https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb] could not be loaded. Error: You have already activated builder 3.0.0, but your Gemfile requires builder 3.0.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

I'm not sure how to use bundle exec to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this in your commandline

```
 gem install builder --version '3.0.2'
```

& then try to use rails-composer

Comment: Glad! it worked.. mark it as answer if it helped & is exactly what you are looking for! :)